# How to set the "cluster" property in prisma.yml

Tags: react-apollo, prisma, prisma-graphql

Thanks for reading my question in advance. I am just start to use graphql and prisma [following this tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/1-getting-started/).

I have the following Error when `Deploying the Prisma database service`:

```
Error: No cluster set. Please set the "cluster" property in your prisma.yml
    at /Users/judy/howtographql/server/node_modules/graphql-config-extension-prisma/src/index.ts:89:11
    at step (/Users/judy/howtographql/server/node_modules/graphql-config-extension-prisma/dist/index.js:40:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/judy/howtographql/server/node_modules/graphql-config-extension-prisma/dist/index.js:21:53)
    at fulfilled (/Users/judy/howtographql/server/node_modules/graphql-config-extension-prisma/dist/index.js:12:58)
    at <anonymous>
error Command failed with exit code 1.
ERROR: "playground" exited with 1.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I looked over the tutorial to find that there is nothing about how to set the cluster. I wonder how to fix this problem.

The default prisma.yaml is:

```
# the name for the service (will be part of the service's HTTP endpoint)
service: hackernews-graphql-js

# the cluster and stage the service is deployed to
stage: dev

# to disable authentication:
# disableAuth: true
secret: mysecret123

# the file path pointing to your data model
datamodel: datamodel.graphql
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be just that you may have entered an incorrect endpoint address. Please refer https://github.com/prisma/graphql-config-extension-graphcool/issues/8